# Let P be the point where BY and CZ meet. Assume that BY=CZ and PY=PZ. Show that AB=AC.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[image: Link to image: http://i.imgur.com/Q5CjEF4.png]

I've been able to prove that ΔBPC is isosceles using given information that CZ=BY, but I am at a loss with how to prove that ΔBPZ≅ΔCPY. If I could prove this I could show that AB=AC since the equal base angles would make it an isosceles triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$BP=CP$, $PZ=PY$ and $\angle BPZ = \angle CPY$: SAS criterion.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I overlooked that.